# Reset Windows locations hijacked by OneDrive

Tags: windows, windows-10, onedrive

Apparently Windows 10 pulled a smart one and decided that OneDrive should be the default location for My Documents and I would much rather it not be. I have searched alternative options and found this:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-this-pcdocuments-points-to-onedrive/deae70e8-fdc1-4165-a37d-ead64a1f361b?auth=1

Which seems to point to non-existent options in the OneDrive application.

Are there any registry entries I can edit that reset where My Documents etc. are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have uninstalled your OneDrive, you may set the path for My Document fodler via registry.

Locate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`, then find the "Personal" value. Make sure its data value is C:\Users<user name>\Documents.

More information, you may refer to "[Configuration of the My Documents folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/configuration-of-the-my-documents-folder-dfd9a90d-8f80-18d6-e7cc-f1566fc3b10b)".

(Please note, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, [back up the registry for restoration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756) in case problems occur.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn off **OneDrive** `"Backup"` (which relocates the users default folders to OneDrive). That will reset the folders under **This PC** to the default locations, but not move any files that have been stored in the OneDrive folders. You have to move them back manually.

To access OneDrive settings, right-click the icon in the Notification Area. If you don't see the icon there, click `Start`, type `OneDrive` and launch the **OneDrive** app.

1. From the context menu of the OneDrive icon, select `Settings`.
2. Click the `Backup` tab and select `Manage Backup`.
3. De-select all three folders and close the dialog.